# Can we Assign an ArrayList like an normal 1D array to the Excel range?

Tags: excel, vbscript, wsh, vba

Consider the below ArrayList:

```
   Dim myAL As New ArrayList()
    myAL.Add("The")
    myAL.Add("quick")
    myAL.Add("brown")
    myAL.Add("fox")
    myAL.Add("jumped")
    myAL.Add("over")
    myAL.Add("the")
    myAL.Add("lazy")
    myAL.Add("dog")
```

So Now Can we set its values to the Excel range horizontally?or before doing that we need to need perform any conversions?

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

    Dim myQueue,i
    Set myQueue = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    'Dim Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary

    myQueue.Add("jumped")
    myQueue.Add("over")
    myQueue.Add("")
    myQueue.Add("")
    myQueue.Add("dog")
    myQueue.Add("Cat")

    i=0
    Do While myQueue.Count > i

      MsgBox(myQueue(i))
    i=i+1
    Loop

    MsgBox("Capacity=" & myQueue.Capacity & "Count:" & myQueue.Count)

    myQueue.Remove("dog")

    MsgBox("Capacity=" & myQueue.Capacity & "Count:" & myQueue.Count)

    i=0
    Do While myQueue.Count > i

      MsgBox(myQueue(i))
    i=i+1
    Loop
```

When we perform any remove operation,then will the ArrayList size will be adjusted automatically like dictionary objects or we need to take care of the size using any `(Re)Dim` statement?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to set the ArrayList to an array:

```
listArray = myAl.ToArray()
```

Then to paste Horizontally:

```
Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(listArray, 1) + 1) = listArray
```

To Paste vertically:

```
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(listArray, 1) + 1) = Application.Transpose(listArray)
```

When you remove items using Remove / RemoveRange you can call the `.Count` property to get the updated size of the array. There is no Ubound/ LBound on an arraylist.

Comment: Could you please look into the last part of my description?

Comment: so after removal, would it be a contiguous array like dictionary keys or removed cells will be left as blank?

Comment: it will be contiguous. If you remove an element all other elements are repositioned if appropriate.

Comment: then its size will be decreased right,if we remove and if added then size of array will be increased automatically.right?

Comment: is the statement ` myAL.Add("")` also a valid statement? or such an element will be removed? how `Arraylist` object will treat such cases when i would add intentionally `""` to meet any purpose?

Comment: adding an empty string to an arraylist is valid yes. I would suggest you test all permutations in VBA and if you have any issues with the code you are not able to solve post another question.

Comment: Sure,I will if I have. Then one question- so after removal how the Arraylist verify that which cells are empty for item removal and which Item is being added as empty string intentionally?

Comment: when an item is removed the item no longer exists in the ArrayList. When you add a value with an empty string as an item it exists and takes up space in the arraylist. The two are very different.

Comment: Yes I agree with you 100%.I just tried and result came as per the logic. see the `UPDATE`